# Compare Keys in Two Dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, compare, intersect, except

I'm trying to compare two dictionaries, the program is written in C# Visual Studio 2010.

```
Dictionary<int, string> members1 = new Dictionaries<int, string>{
    {1, "adam"},
    {2, "bob"},
    {3, "cameron"}
}

Dictionary<int, string> members2 = new Dictionaries<int, string>{
    {1, "adam"},
    {2, "bill"},
    {4, "dave"}
}
```

I would like to find the same id (key), and it doesn't matter if the name (value) is the same or not.

I've been searching and found `Intersect` and `Except`, but I don't think it work quite the way I wanted it.

With the example above, if I call an `Intersect` function, I want it to return `List<int>{1, 2}`.

If I call something like `members1.Except(members2)`, I want it to return

```
Dictionary<int, string> intersectMembers{
    {1, "adam"},
}
```

A solution I thought of doing is to write 2 for-loops and using `dictionary.Contains(key)` to get the result I want.

Is there a more straight forward way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a "Common **Dictionary**" returned I believe you could do it this way:

```
   var intersectMembers =  members1.Keys.Intersect(members2.Keys)
                                  .ToDictionary(t => t, t => members1[t]);
```

or, **alternatively**:

```
   var intersectMembers =  members1.Where(x => members2.ContainsKey(x.Key))
                             .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

**However**, if you want a "Common **List**" returned then Sergey is right and you can implement his answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
 var commonKeys = members1.Keys.Intersect(members2.Keys); // { 1, 2 }
```

That will return `IEnumerable<int>` but you can call `ToList()` if you want list.

Comment: I thought he wanted a third dictionary?

Comment: @JasonRoell but OP stated *I want it to return List<int>{1, 2}*

Comment: Oh I guess I just saw the part about "If I call something like members1.Except(members2), I want it to return

Dictionary<int, string> intersectMembers{
    {1, "adam"},
}"

Comment: Agree, question can be interpreted that way also, +1 from me

Comment: Either way works for me. I though by returning the list I can still simply construct a third dictionary using value in the list as the key. I think its just a matter of 1 step or two steps. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I would accept both yours and Jasons answer, but he had answered before you. Thank you so much.